# Align images in main section

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert 3 images in my main section. I want to align them but my third image stays at the bottom of my page. I tried to shrink the images but nothing change. I used "margin-left" "margin-bottom" and "float" but nothing works.

```css
main section h1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  float: left;
}

main section h2 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

main section h3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: it's better to write your code in `codepen` and set the link in your question to solve that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`, for example:

HTML

```
<body>
<div>
    <img src='1.jpg'>
    <img src='2.jpg'>
    <img src='3.jpg'>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;//ALIGN DIV VERTICALLY
    }

    div{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;//ALIGN IMG'S HORIZONTALLY
        width: 100%;
    }

    img{
        width: 300px;
        height: 180px;
    }

    img:nth-of-type(2){
        margin: 0 20px
    }
```

Look the result in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqXKU.jpg